# get reference of a user control in dependent project

Tags: asp.net

Summary :

Project1 contains a user control tab1.ascx (basically a collection of panels 1, 2 , 3 etc.)

Project2 is referenced in Project1.

Project2 contains a master page (MasterPage.cs) where I want to call this user control (tab1.ascx).

Reason for calling the user control from project 2 is that I can centrally control enabling / disabling of tabs from master page based on the user privileges.
For e.g. for admin, all the tabs will be visible.
for a normal user, only the first tab will be visible.

Problem:

I am unable to add the reference of Project 1 in Project 2 (circular dependency).

I am able to find the control and I can use a cast (System.Web.UI.UserControl) but this cast doesn't help me call the methods of the actual user control - tab1.ascx

Is there any way I can reference the user control in Project 2?

edited:
using the following code I am able to call the method:

tab1.GetType().InvokeMember("DisableTab", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, tab1, new object[] { "Conf Tests" });

Now, it is actually calling the DisableTab method of the user control. But it is unable to find the items within it.  theTabStr.Items returns 0.

theTabStr is actually a repeater control.

```
    public void DisableTab(string strTabName)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem itmRptr in theTabStr.Items)
        {
            LinkButton lnkbtnTab = (LinkButton)itmRptr.FindControl("theTab");
            if (lnkbtnTab != null && lnkbtnTab.Text == strTabName)
            {
                lnkbtnTab.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why there is a referrence between projects now? If project1 contains other elements, you should separate this one into two projects - one with other elements (e.g. project3) and one with tab1.ascx (proj4). After all, you'd proj3->proj2, proj2->proj4.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your circular dependency problem.  Re-think your design.  If something needs to be shared between the two projects, then it stands to reason that you can probably create a third project to encapsulate the control.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would declare interface, lets say

```
interface IControl {
    void foo();
}
```

in Project2, have this tab1.ascx implement this interface, and type control once you find it to this interface. (This interface can be also defined in Project3 that will be referenced by both Project1 and Project2).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible for User Controls.

If you want to share Custom Controls across project bordaries, you will have to create a custom control in a separate DLL which inherits from Control or an existing control as explained in this msdn article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy(v=vs.100).aspx

If you DO want to use the usercontrol you created, you will have to copy it into your "project2"

Comment: can't I use assembly functions ?